# How to select data from two tables with query builder in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this query which works perfectly on MySql 5

```
'SELECT a.id, a.name, a.date, c.name FROM artist as a, country as c WHERE a.country_id=c.id'
```

Basically it selects the id, name and date from the artist table and then replaces the id of the country with its appropriate name from the country table.

Note: artist.country_id is foreign key i.e. country.id. Every artist belongs to some country and it has a country_id in its table. I need to take data for the artist but also replace the country_id with its appropriate name. I don't want to show number for the country, I want to show country's name.

```
 $artists = $this->db->query('SELECT a.id, a.name, a.date, c.name FROM artist as a, country as c WHERE a.country_id=c.id');
```

The problem I face is, artist.name gets overwritten by country.name and I don't see the artist name in the result, only the country name.

How can I get this working under CodeIgniter query builder?

I use CodeIgniter version 3.

Edit: More code added:

```
    $this->db->select('artist.id', 'artist.name', 'artist.date', 'country.name', false);
    $this->db->from('artist');
    $this->db->join('country', 'country.id=artist.country_id');
    $artists = $this->db->get();
```

Part of the result:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Macedonia
        [date] => 1979-10-10
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Britain
        [date] => 2003-01-01
    )
```

No artist name in the result. Country name overwrites this field.

[image: artist table query with country name]

Comment: look up **join** method of query builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write subquery as below

```
 $this->db->
 select('a.id, a.name, a.date, c.name')
 ->from('artist as a, country as c ')
 ->where('a.country_id','c.id');
```

you can also do using `joins`

```
$this->db->select('a.id as artist_id, a.name as artist_name, a.date as artist_date, c.name as country_name',false)
$this->db->from('artist as a')
$this->db->join('country as c','a.country_id = c.id');
```

to access the values.

$row->artist_id
$row->artist_name etc...

Comment: Tried your code with join, i get only the id of the artist. I also added more code to the question.

Comment: I get error because the join function accepts two arguments.

Comment: artist.country_id is foreign key from country, which is country.id

Comment: i bit confuse.if both are foreign key then join return as desire result.you dont need to use `where` condition.

Comment: i still get only id, and other fields are missing. Need to investigate.

Comment: you cannot use the same index to get both properties at once.in your query `on country_id = id then use alias instead table name.try with my answer

Comment: The false param does make a difference but I get the same result as the query in the original post. No name of the artist. Replaced with name of the country.

Comment: i bit confused.can you show me your table structure with desire result

Comment: " No name of the artist. Replaced with name of the country." how do you want replace? i cant understod.

Comment: How hard it is to understand? Every artist belongs to some country and it has a country_id in its table. I need to take data for the artist but also replace the country_id with its appropriate name. I don't want to show number for the country, I want to show country's name. But yes I will put this in the description. Thanks for the note.

Comment: use alias name instead of real name.